# $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(0{,}999 + \frac{1}{n})^{n+3} = $. Did I do it right?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I need to find the limit of this expression:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} (0{,}999 + \frac{1}{n})^{n+3} = e^{(n+3)\ln(0{,}999+\frac{1}{n})} = e^{(n+3)[\ln(\frac{1}{n})+\ln(1+0{,}999n)]}$$

Therefore:

- $\lim_{n \to +\infty} 0{,}999n = 0$
- $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \ln(1+0{,}999n) = 0$

And I get:

$$e^{(n+3)[\ln(\frac{1}{n})+ln(1+0{,}999n)]} \implies e^{(n+3)\ln(\frac{1}{n})} = e^{\ln(\frac{1}{n^{n+3}})}$$

- $\ln(\frac{1}{n^{n+3}}) \implies -\infty $

So:

$$e^{\ln(\frac{1}{n^{n+3}})} \implies e^{-\infty} \implies 0$$

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}(0{,}999 + \frac{1}{n})^{n+3} = 0$$

Did I do it right?

Comment: It's much easier than that — this isn't an indeterminate form. For $n\gt 2000$ you have $0.999+\frac1n \lt 0.9995$, so $(.999+\frac1n)^{n+3}\lt.9995^{n+3}$.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\left(0.999+\frac1n\right)^{n+3}&=\left(0.999+\frac1n\right)^{n}\left(0.999+\frac1n\right)^{3}\\\\
&=\underbrace{(0.999)^n}_{\to 0}\,\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1/0.999}{n}\right)^n}_{\to e^{1/0.999}}\underbrace{\left(0.999+\frac1n\right)^{3}}_{\to (0.999)^3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Tip: If you use a comma as the decimal separator, the spacing looks better when you typeset it `0{,}999` giving $0{,}999$ instead of `0,999` that looks like $0,999$. The reason is that in the part of the world TeX was designed, a point is used as the decimal separator, and a comma is a list separator. Therefore TeX (and hence also MathJax) interprets `0,999` as a list of two numbers $0$ and $999$ separated by a comma. And then it makes sense to add a tiny amount of space after the comma. The curly braces fix that.

Comment: It should be pointed out that $\lim_{n\to\infty}0.999n=\infty$, not $0$, and that this invalidates most of the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the case more general looking at
$$t_n=\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+b}\implies \log(t_n)=(n+b)\log\left(a+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
Now, using Taylor
$$\log(t_n)=(n+b)\left(\log (a)+\frac{1}{a n}-\frac{1}{2 a^2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right)$$
$$\log(t_n)=n \log (a)+\left(b \log (a)+\frac{1}{a}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$t_n=e^{\log(t_n)}=e^{\frac{1}{a}} a^b\, n^a+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ So, as soon as $a < 1$, your conclusion.

Comment: Is $x_n = t_n$?

Comment: @Keba. Sorry fot the typo !